# Slow query, should i index or other solutions?

Tags: mysql

I have this very slow query, it counts the product that has certain specifications, is the solution indexing? or other solutions?

```
select count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Meisje'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count1 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Jongen'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count2 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Unisex'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count3  from (products p)
                        join (products_to_categories p2c)
                          on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
                        left join (specials s)
                          on (p.products_id = s.products_id)
                        left join (products_attributes pa)
                          on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
                        left join (products_options_values pv)
                          on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
                        left join (products_stock ps)
                          on (p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2)        
                                             INNER JOIN products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  INNER JOIN products_specifications ps17 ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id  where p.products_status = '1' and ps.products_stock_quantity>0   and p2c.categories_id in (2,54,60,82,109,115,116,118,53,58,104,55,101,75,56,64,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,103,114,80,92,99,93,94,95,97,106)  AND ps10.specifications_id = '10'
                  AND ps10.language_id = '1'
                   AND ps17.specification in ('Babyslofjes'
                              ) AND ps17.specifications_id = '17'
                  AND ps17.language_id = '1'
```

explain this query gives me this results:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table |  type  |            possible_keys            |                 key                 | key_len |                   ref                    | rows  |          Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps    | ALL    | idx_products_stock_attributes       | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL                                     | 16216 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | kikleding.ps.products_id                 |     1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref    | idx_specials_products_id            | idx_specials_products_id            | 4       | kikleding.p.products_id                  |     1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2c   | ref    | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | kikleding.ps.products_id                 |     1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pv    | ref    | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | kikleding.ps.products_options_values_id2 |     1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps10  | ref    | products_id                         | products_id                         | 12      | kikleding.p.products_id,const,const      |     1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps17  | ref    | products_id                         | products_id                         | 12      | kikleding.ps.products_id,const,const     |     1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pa    | ref    | idx_products_attributes_products_id | idx_products_attributes_products_id | 4       | kikleding.p2c.products_id                |     6 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Changed the left joins to inner joins like this:

```
select count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Meisje'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count1 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Jongen'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count2 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Unisex'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count3  from (products p)
                        inner join (products_to_categories p2c)
                          on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
                        left join (specials s)
                          on (p.products_id = s.products_id)
                        inner join (products_attributes pa)
                          on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
                        inner join (products_options_values pv)
                          on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
                        inner join (products_stock ps)
                          on (p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2)        
                                             INNER JOIN products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  INNER JOIN products_specifications ps17 ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id  where p.products_status = '1' and ps.products_stock_quantity>0   and p2c.categories_id in (2,54,60,82,109,115,116,118,53,58,104,55,101,75,56,64,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,103,114,80,92,99,93,94,95,97,106)  AND ps10.specifications_id = '10'
                  AND ps10.language_id = '1'
                   AND ps17.specification in ('Babyslofjes'
                              ) AND ps17.specifications_id = '17'
                  AND ps17.language_id = '1'
```

I Indexed the ps.products_id

It's little bit faster, thank you for the comments, but the query is still very slow

Comment: Maybe you should remove all the redundant joins/tables and replace the left joins which are not returning unjoined rows with inner joins first?

Comment: You have a check for ps.products_stock_quantity>0 in your WHERE clause. For that to be true you must have a matching ps record, and to get that you must have pv and pa records. So change those to inner joins. Do you have an index on ps.products_id?

Comment: thank you i changed this to inner join like this:
    inner join (products_attributes pa)
                          on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
                        inner join (products_options_values pv)
                          on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
                        inner join (products_stock ps)

and indexed ps.products_id , it a little faster but still very slow

Comment: Can you post the table definitions, at least for products_stock. Possibly worth trying changing inner join (products_stock ps) to STRAIGHT_JOIN (products_stock ps)

Comment: you mean like this?
products_stock_id | products_id | products_stock_attributes | products_stock_quantity | products_options_values_id2

Answer (score 0):

As obvious use p.products_id more so first index that attribute in table Products. Then pv.products_options_values_id and also try to index other attributes you use in Inner Join. Also try to convert where conditions to be used with in Join conditions expecially for Inner join

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a slightly modified query to put the conditions into the join from the where parts, and from the sample I'd think you could get rid of the Specials table as well.

```
select
  count(distinct if(ps10.specification in ('Meisje'), p.products_id, null)) as count1,
  count(distinct if(ps10.specification in ('Jongen'), p.products_id, null)) as count2,
  count(distinct if(ps10.specification in ('Unisex'), p.products_id, null)) as count3
from (products p)
  inner join (products_to_categories p2c)
    on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
  inner join (products_attributes pa)
    on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
  inner join (products_options_values pv)
    on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
  inner join (products_stock ps)
    on (p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2 and ps.products_stock_quantity > 0)        
  inner join products_specifications ps10
    ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id and ps10.language_id = '1' and ps10.specifications_id = '10'
  inner join products_specifications ps17
    ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id and ps17.language_id = '1' and ps17.specifications_id = '17'
where p.products_status = '1'
  and p2c.categories_id in (2,54,60,82,109,115,116,118,53,58,104,55,101,75,56,64,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,103,114,80,92,99,93,94,95,97,106)
  and ps17.specification in ('Babyslofjes')
```

As for the indexes, I'd check the following to be available:

- products / products_id (most probably is)
- products_to_categories / products_id+categories_id (most probably also)
- products_attributes / products_id+options_values_id
- products_options_values / products_options_values_id
- products_specifications / products_id+language_id+specifications_id

From the table names I suspect this being an OS/XTcommerce database, I'll try to get my hands on one in a few hours and give a more detailed opinion. I just don't remember products_stock and products_specifications, those are both tables, not views, right?

Comment: the slightly modification gives slightly improvement which is very good, thank you for that

Comment: it's an oscommerce database. products_stock and product_specifications are tables from installed conrtibutions